# Use an Alias in Where Clause Subquery

Tags: oracle, subquery

I need to show some fields from another table in Oracle. Here is my query:

```
SELECT
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ID_PEGAWAI AS KODE,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.NAMA,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.NIP,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.JABATAN,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.GOLONGAN,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.PANGKAT,
    (SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(abs(sysdate
    - TO_DATE(TMT_JABATAN))/360,'9,999,999.9'),' TAHUN') 
       FROM SIMPEG_JABATAN where ID_PEGAWAI=KODE ORDER BY TMT_JABATAN desc)
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1) AS MASA_KERJA
FROM 
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI
    INNER JOIN ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN 
        ON ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ESELON_JABATAN = 
        ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.ID_ESELON_JABATAN
    INNER JOIN ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT 
        ON ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.PANGKAT = 
        ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.ID_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT
WHERE
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ST_AKTIF = 1 AND
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ESELON2 <> 1 AND
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.PANGKAT >= 12 AND 
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.STATUS = 1 AND
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.ID_ESELON2=2
ORDER BY
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.SORT DESC
```

The result I got:

```
[Err] ORA-00904: "KODE": invalid identifier
```

`KODE` come from query `ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ID_PEGAWAI AS KODE`, and used for this query :

```
(SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(abs(sysdate - 
    TO_DATE(TMT_JABATAN))/360,'9,999,999.9'),' TAHUN') 
            FROM SIMPEG_JABATAN where ID_PEGAWAI=KODE ORDER BY TMT_JABATAN desc)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1) AS MASA_KERJA
```

Do I miss something? Or could be using an alias in subquery wrong in the `where` clause in Oracle?

edited:
I have solved this problem, thanks for every one, here it is:

```
select
  e.nama as nama,
  e.nip  as nip,
    f.golongan as golongan,
    f.pangkat as pangkat_golongan,  
    g.jabatan as jabatan_akhir,
    sub.tmt_jabatan as lama_menjabat,
    sub.kualifikasi as kualifikasi,
    sub.hari as hari_kerja
from 
  simpeg_pegawai e,
  (
    select
      j.id_pegawai as id_pegawai,
            extract(year from (sysdate - j.tmt_jabatan) year to month) || ' Tahun ' ||
            extract(month from (sysdate - j.tmt_jabatan) year to month) || ' Bulan ' 
            tmt_jabatan,
            extract(year from (sysdate - j.tmt_jabatan) year to month) kualifikasi,
            trunc((((86400*(sysdate-j.tmt_jabatan))/60)/60)/24) as hari,
      row_number()
        over (
          partition by j.id_pegawai
          order by     j.tmt_jabatan desc
        ) as job_order
    from
      simpeg_jabatan j
  ) sub,simpeg_kode_golongan_pangkat f, simpeg_eselon_jabatan g

where 
        sub.id_pegawai = e.id_pegawai
        and e.pangkat = f.id_golongan_pangkat
        and e.eselon_jabatan = g.id_eselon_jabatan
        and g.id_eselon2 = 2
        and g.status = 1
        and e.st_aktif=1
        and e.eselon2=2
        and e.pangkat >= 12
        and sub.job_order = 1
        and sub.kualifikasi > = 2
order by sub.hari desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@haki has identified why this error occurs. You can't use an alias (`KODE`) defined in the `SELECT` list, in the definition of another column in that list. You have to use the full reference instead (`ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ID_PEGAWAI`).

But the solution provided, does not work I think because of the double nesting. You can reference a column in a inline subquery but not in a derived table inside an inline subquery.

This would require either using `ROW_NUMBER()` and encapsulating the whole query ina derived table or turning the inline subquery into a `LEFT JOIN.` But since you have `ROWNUM=1` and `ORDER BY TMT_JABATAN desc` and you are selecting only `TMT_JABATAN` in that inline subquery, you can use `MAX(TMT_JABATAN)` instead and one-level nesting:

```
SELECT
    sp.ID_PEGAWAI AS KODE,
    sp.NAMA,
    sp.NIP,
    sej.JABATAN,
    skgp.GOLONGAN,
    skgp.PANGKAT,
    ( SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(abs(sysdate - TO_DATE(MAX(sj.TMT_JABATAN)))/360,'9,999,999.9'),
                    ' TAHUN') 
      FROM SIMPEG_JABATAN  sj
      WHERE sj.ID_PEGAWAI = sp.ID_PEGAWAI  
    ) AS MASA_KERJA
FROM 
        ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI  sp
    INNER JOIN ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN   sej
        ON sp.ESELON_JABATAN = sej.ID_ESELON_JABATAN
    INNER JOIN ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT  skgp
        ON sp.PANGKAT = skgp.ID_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT
WHERE
    sp.ST_AKTIF = 1 AND
    sp.ESELON2 <> 1 AND
    sp.PANGKAT >= 12 AND 
    sej.STATUS = 1 AND
    sej.ID_ESELON2 = 2
ORDER BY
    skgp.SORT DESC ;
```

Comment: thanks that work nicely dude, i have solved this one before yours, but i appriciate your answer because it works tu, i have update my code to working one, thanks dude

Comment: I think it's better if you posted your solution as an answer. (and remove it from the question)

Comment: how i do that ? i have update my question to solved one

Comment: You add the code (that solves your problem) in the "Your Answer" area, below.

Comment: Sorry, there's an ***"Answer Your Question"*** button for you to do that.

Comment: What is the reference for why an alias isn't allowed to be used in this case?

Comment: @HansVonn you can't reference a column alias in the same SELECT list, as that would result in ambiguous reference cycles. Example: `SELECT a+c AS a, 2*a+c AS b, a+b AS c FROM t;` (where table `t` has a column `a` but not  `b` or `c`).

Comment: Thank you. I am more interested in a reference to a standard that declares this. Perhaps that is better as its own question though.

Comment: @HansVonn Oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2126854 : expr

Specify an expression representing the information you want to select. A column name in this list can be qualified with schema only if the table, view, or materialized view containing the column is qualified with schema in the FROM clause. If you specify a member method of an object type, then you must follow the method name with parentheses even if the method takes no arguments.*""*

Comment: And even better: *"c_alias Specify an alias for the column expression. Oracle Database will use this alias in the column heading of the result set. The AS keyword is optional. The alias effectively renames the select list item for the duration of the query. The alias can be used in the order_by_clause but **not other clauses** in the query."*

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ thank you, that helps. I was looking for a standard (more especially for tsql) and this is a good direction.

Answer (score 1):

you cant use alias from the wraping query in the a sub query
change it this way

```
SELECT
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ID_PEGAWAI AS KODE,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.NAMA,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.NIP,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.JABATAN,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.GOLONGAN,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.PANGKAT,
    (SELECT *
            FROM (SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(abs(sysdate - TO_DATE(TMT_JABATAN))/360,'9,999,999.9'),' TAHUN') 
                FROM SIMPEG_JABATAN where ID_PEGAWAI=ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ID_PEGAWAI  ORDER BY TMT_JABATAN desc)
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1) AS MASA_KERJA
FROM 
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI
    INNER JOIN ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN 
        ON ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ESELON_JABATAN = ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.ID_ESELON_JABATAN
    INNER JOIN ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT 
        ON ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.PANGKAT = ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.ID_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT
WHERE
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ST_AKTIF = 1 AND
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ESELON2 <> 1 AND
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.PANGKAT >= 12 AND 
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.STATUS = 1 AND
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.ID_ESELON2=2
ORDER BY
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.SORT DESC
```

remember, sql engine process a query in the following order

1. from
2. where
3. group by
4. having
5. select

so, when you execute the inner query the sql engine does no know the aliad `KODE` yet.

Comment: The explanation of why the error occurs is correct. I'm not sure if your proposal is valid syntax though.

Comment: i cant check the syntax but all i did was to change the alias `KODE` in the inner query to `ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ID_PEGAWAI`. is it not working ?

Comment: I'm not sure because of the double nesting. Can you check?

Comment: you can reference any column from the outer query at any level of sub query. this should not be a problem. do you get an syntax error when you try to execute the query ?